# AJP connections leak in Glassfish 3.0.1

Tags: apache2, glassfish-3

It seems that when using Apache 2.2 with mod_jk to route request to a virtual host pointing to a back-end Glassfish  3.0.1 server on AJP connection (8009), any request will cause a connection leak on the Glashfish end

None of the connection timeout settings on Glassfish seem to work. When the number of leaked connections reaches the maximum number of threads in the thread-pool that is assigned to the ajp network listener, the Glassfish server becomes unresponsive but still won't free up any opened connections no matter how old they are (1 days ...). Strange behavior for a server connection

Has anyone experienced the same issue and solved the problem?
Thank you

Peter

Comment: is there any firewall between your Apache and glassfish?